Upload API with formData object as payload taking too long
I am hitting an upload API with formdata object as payload
The issue is this is taking 30seconds to 1minute to be received by server from my machine. Rest of my team mates updated their browsers and this time reduced to 2-3 seconds. But still for me it is taking approximately 1min even after updating my browser.
What can i do to reduce this time?

You should sample code so it's easy to see what you are doing wrong and resolve.
